# Flutter ios build error Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, flutter, build

After I update Flutter to 2.10.3, I faced this issue. I attach full issue here.

> PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script
> /Users/oniangel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-actqjocawbpvxthcghifvxqbvaef/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh
> (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
> cd /Users/oniangel/Downloads/iTombs_Mobile-f18b238ce9e7f34c4621612fe8dea397a822c6cf/ios
> export ACTION=build
> export AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=YES
> export ALTERNATE_GROUP=staff
> export ALTERNATE_MODE=u+w,go-w,a+rX
> export ALTERNATE_OWNER=oniangel
> export ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=YES
> export ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS=NO
> export ALWAYS_USE_SEPARATE_HEADERMAPS=NO
> export APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR=/AppleInternal/Developer
> export APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR=/AppleInternal
> export APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR=/AppleInternal/Documentation
> export APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR=/AppleInternal/Library
> export APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS=/AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
> export APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY=NO
> export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES=NO
> export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_HEADERS=NO
> export ARCHS=x86_64
> export ARCHS_STANDARD=arm64\ x86_64
> export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT=arm64\ i386\ x86_64
> export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT=i386
> export ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT=arm64\ x86_64
> export ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT=arm64\ x86_64
> export ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS=arm64\ i386\ x86_64
> export ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME=AppIcon
> export ASSETCATALOG_FILTER_FOR_DEVICE_MODEL=iPhone13,4
> export ASSETCATALOG_FILTER_FOR_DEVICE_OS_VERSION=14.4
> export AVAILABLE_PLATFORMS=appletvos\ appletvsimulator\ iphoneos\ iphonesimulator\ macosx\ watchos\ watchsimulator
> export AppIdentifierPrefix=V8C54S2S2T.
> export BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=marker
> export BUILD_ACTIVE_RESOURCES_ONLY=YES
> export BUILD_COMPONENTS=headers\ build
> export BUILD_DIR=/Users/oniangel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-actqjocawbpvxthcghifvxqbvaef/Build/Products
> export BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=NO
> export BUILD_ROOT=/Users/oniangel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-actqjocawbpvxthcghifvxqbvaef/Build/Products
> export BUILD_STYLE=
> export BUILD_VARIANTS=normal
> export BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR=/Users/oniangel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-actqjocawbpvxthcghifvxqbvaef/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
> export BUNDLE_CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH_deep=Contents/
> export BUNDLE_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_NAME_deep=MacOS
> export BUNDLE_FORMAT=shallow
> export BUNDLE_FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH=Frameworks
> export BUNDLE_PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH=PlugIns
> export BUNDLE_PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH=PrivateHeaders
> export BUNDLE_PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH=Headers
> export CACHE_ROOT=/var/folders/jv/s4fdw_r95xzb2btlwb3xpn6m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/12.4-12D4e/Xcode
> export CCHROOT=/var/folders/jv/s4fdw_r95xzb2btlwb3xpn6m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/12.4-12D4e/Xcode
> export CHMOD=/bin/chmod
> export CHOWN=/usr/sbin/chown
> export CLANG_ANALYZER_NONNULL=YES
> export CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD=gnu++0x
> export CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY=libc++
> export CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES=YES
> export CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC=YES
> export CLANG_MODULES_BUILD_SESSION_FILE=/Users/oniangel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation
> export CLANG_WARN_BLOCK_CAPTURE_AUTORELEASING=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_BOOL_CONVERSION=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_COMMA=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE=YES_ERROR
> export CLANG_WARN_EMPTY_BODY=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_INFINITE_RECURSION=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_INT_CONVERSION=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_NON_LITERAL_NULL_CONVERSION=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_LITERAL_CONVERSION=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_ROOT_CLASS=YES_ERROR
> export CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER=NO
> export CLANG_WARN_RANGE_LOOP_ANALYSIS=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_STRICT_PROTOTYPES=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_SUSPICIOUS_MOVE=YES
> export CLANG_WARN_UNREACHABLE_CODE=YES
> export CLANG_WARN__DUPLICATE_METHOD_MATCH=YES
> export CLASS_FILE_DIR=/Users/oniangel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-actqjocawbpvxthcghifvxqbvaef/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/JavaClasses
> export CLEAN_PRECOMPS=YES
> export CLONE_HEADERS=NO
> export COCOAPODS_PARALLEL_CODE_SIGN=true
> export CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH=/Users/oniangel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-actqjocawbpvxthcghifvxqbvaef/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app
> export CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=YES
> export CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=YES
> export CODE_SIGN_CONTEXT_CLASS=XCiPhoneSimulatorCodeSignContext
> export CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=Runner/Runner.entitlements
> export CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=-
> export CODE_SIGN_INJECT_BASE_ENTITLEMENTS=YES
> export COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS=NO
> export COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES=NO
> export COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=Default
>
> ..........
>
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code